# Regex: URL re-writing any path without extension

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting

I've written a regex which "works" for all the test cases I can think of.
Essentially any URL which matches the pattern:

/app.* AND does not have an extension of length 1-4 at the end should be re-written.
I've come up with:

```
/app((?:\\/[\\w([^\\..]{1,4}\b)\\-]+)+)
```

The question is, can this be simplified to achieve the same thing?
Also, could I replace my use of \w with something like .*, I could be wrong but I suspect as soon as I encounter a URL with an odd character it'll break.

EDIT 1:
Example URLs that should match:

```
/app AND /app/
/app/auth
/app/auth/fb
/app/auth/twitter
/app/groups
/app/conn/manage
/app/play
/app/play/migrate
/app/play/migrate/done
```

Example URLs that should NOT match:

```
/app/js/some.file.js
/app/js/jquery.js
/app/styles/default/rain.css
/app/styles/name/file.css
/app/tpl/index.tpl
/app/tpl/file.html
/app/tpl/some.other.tpl
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please give some examples. It will make the question more clear

Comment: `\w` will short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]. You can use `\W` for non word character.

Comment: Yes I know about \w and \W I may be thinking of edge cases more than anything else but I think I should be matching non-alphanumeric chars as well. Some of these URLs may be generated based on user supplied content and I could strip non-alphanumerics but some non-alphas* are allowed in URLs

Comment: So the requirement is that the URL should not contain an extension, right?

Comment: Yes the URL should not contain an extension between 1 and 4 chars at the end. So some.file.js should not match but some.file.random is valid and should match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach is to put all the assets you want the webserver to handle in a single directory. Like `/app/public`, so you would get `app/public/js` and `app/public/html` etc. This will make you have no edge cases and a far easier URL handling.

Anyway, I think the regex below answers the question you asked: match anything except if there is a extension with 1 - 4 characters on the file.

```
^(\/(\w+))*\/?(\.\w{5,})?\??([^.]+)?$
```

http://rubular.com/r/4CQ4amccH5

```
^              //start of anchor
  (
    \/         //match forward slash
    (\w+)      //match any word character, match atleast once 
  )+           //match this group atleast once (this group captures /app/etc/etc)
  \/?          //match a forward slash, make it optional (to also capture /app/)
  (\.\w{5,})?  //match any word after a . with 5 characters or more, make it optional
  \??          //match a ?, make the match optional
  ([^.]+)?     //match anything not containing a . 1 or more times, make the match optional
$              //end of anchor
```

This still needs some work to make it work in Java, mainly alot of escaping escape characters.

Comment: Thanks, In a month or so I'll be able to do a refactor and then I'll change the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be:

```
/app(/\w+)*/?$
```

I assumed you want to match a url with word characters that may end up with a slash but not a file extension.